# How to pass SQL database data from one activity to another?

Tags: android, sql, database, android-intent

I have a simple application consisting in a contacts database (using a SQLiteDatabase class).

In my main activity layout, there is a "View Contacts" button. When pressed, I create a new activity (let's call it "ContactsActivity") in order to show a LinearLayout with the contacts data.

My question is: how can I give ContactsActivity access to the database? 
Do I pass some data from the main activity (which I think is not an option)? 
Do I just kind of open the database from this activity?
Do I use the same method that I used for the main activity (I mean, using a SQLiteOpenHelper and so)?

I don't know if I am giving enough information; otherwise, just ask me and I will provide any necessary info.

Thank you.

Comment: just pass `id` or the whole `Uri` identifying your contact

Comment: *Do I use the same method that I used for the main activity (I mean, using a SQLiteOpenHelper and so)?* totally do this.

Comment: and for God sake dont use any `ArrayAdapter` / `BaseAdapter`, instead use `SimpleCursorAdapter` with your `ListView`

Comment: Ok @RahulTiwari , so if I do this, I'll create a new table that's identical to the one I create for the main activity in order to do other operations, but the database is the same one, right?

Comment: @MarcosRodriguez no. don't create new tables perform operations on same tables

Comment: @RahulTiwari But if in the "onCreate" method of the SQLiteOpenHelper class, I use the line "db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);", aren't I creating a new table? If I have to use the same table from two different activities, I guess I have to change that line.

Comment: onCreate from DB helper will get called only once in entire lifetime of your DB. that's a lifecycle method and not meant to be called manually.